# How can I extract AGL data from a Foreflight generated KML

Tags: google-earth, tracklog

I'm wondering how I can extract the actual Above Ground Level data from a foreflight generated KML file. Our pilots fly at 500'-700' AGL levels for work purposes. When I pull the KML into Google Earth Pro, the data displayed in the elevation profile shows elevations in the 1000s of feet which is definitely not correct. I've changed the altitude settings in the property tab (clamped to ground, absolute, etc.) and it does display different altitudes but they all remain in the 1000s of feet. Is there a way to get this data in Google Earth Pro or do I need some other program to extract this info?

Comment: Where does the elevation value in your KML come from?  Some on-board GNSS unit?  An altimeter?